# NumberFormatException when trying to convert String to int while using split() method

Tags: java

```
string = "#1x#2#3#4#5#6#";

    String array[] = string.split("#");
    for(int count=0;count<=6;count++){
        // String temp = array[count];
        String temp1 = array[count].substring(0,1).trim();//here temp1="1"
        //  String temp1 = "1"; //this is possible 
        log (Integer.parseInt( temp1));// i cant convert the array which is populated by split("delimiter") why ??
    }
```

Here's the array:

```
array[]=("1","2","3","4","5","6"}
```

I can convert the the String array[] into integer when i am declaring this as normal String array but when i am using split and populating the String array here in this example .

I am ready to explain if you can't understand too. Help me out in this?
The Error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
```

My question is Integer.parseInt(string_array_populated_by_split_method[count]) is throwing Exception

**Here the return value is a string "1" i.e Integer.parseInt("1").. this "1" is generated by split() method**

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a

```
substring(0, 0)
```

which is returning `""`, and `""` cannot be converted to int. If you want to get the first character, you need to do:

```
substring(0, 1)
```

Then why you are trimming a single character, I don't know...

**Edit**

Your new problem is:

The fact that your String starts with a `#` means that the first value in your array will be a `""`, and this one is causing problem. What you can do is testing that the String length is superior that 0:

```
for(String current : array){
    if(current.length() > 0) {  
        String temp1 = current.substring(0,1);
        log (Integer.parseInt( temp1));
    }
}
```

Or you could also make sure that your String at the beginning isn't starting with a `#`.

Comment: No.. substring(start,end) will return the substring start (inclusive)

Comment: Oh really? Have you tested it?... believe me, you definitely need to do `substring(0,1)` to get the first character.

Comment: u are right.. i have edited my post.. well .. the thing i want to ask is not substring or trim !!  I initially mentioned wrong.. !! 
log(Integer.parseInt(array[count].substring(0)));//return the value String "1" right ?? whent trying this string its throwing the error.. i have mentioned earlier... why cant i convert to int..?? try this i tested

Comment: This is my question initially i was not explaining it properly.. can u understand now ??

Comment: @Pradeepraj Ok, so is it fixed now?

Answer (score 1):

I'd be include to split on non-digits, that way you *only* get digits:

```
 String array[] = string.split("\\D");
```

I would also skip anything that's a blank, which you get from split if your input ends or starts with a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your example string contains "1x" so just using "#" as delimeter will give you "1x" which you cant parse into int.

Secondly empty string may be returned by split if there was nothing ahead of the delimeter. so you should check for empty string.

Your program should be something like:

```
String string = "#1x#2#3#4#5#6#";
String array[] = string.split("\\D");
for (int count = 0; count < array.length; count++) {
    if (!array[count].isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(array[count]));
}
```

Comment: Firstly your example string contains "1x" so just using "#" as delimeter will give you "1x" which you cant parse into int.
Yes.. It will give "1x" but substring(0,1) will return 1 alone 
am i right ?? why cant we convert "1" to int
thanks for the info Empty string .. I will try to figure out this

Comment: yeah as like u said i am using consecutive delimiters for a string.. But the sample given in this page works for this case.. U said"empty string may be returned by split" may be.. u are right i will verify and test this

Comment: >>It will give "1x" but substring(0,1) will return 1 alone am i right ?? Yes, but what if you have 2 digit number? It is cleaner to use non-digits as delimiter in this case. Using debugger or just printing out the strings will give you better insight.

Answer (score 0):

When split() encounters two consequitive delimiters it returns an empty string.  Between 1 and 2 you have a comma and a space.

Comment: There was a space before.. But that was my mistake .. I presented my question now in a clear manner.. now